# Feeding the TEA Cipher without flooding ram

Tags: c++

How would it be possible to feed the [TEA cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm) without exceeding a systems ram with large files?
I have tried doing this however it has all ended with massive failure and hours of tinkering that leads to nothing. So could someone give me an example of how this can be done or any meaningful information on how to do it?

```
void decodeXtea(unsigned int* v, unsigned int* w, unsigned int* k) {
    register unsigned int v0=v[0], v1=v[1], i, sum=0xC6EF3720;
    register unsigned int delta=0x9E3779B9;
    for(i=0; i<32; i++) {
        v1 -= (((v0 << 4) ^ (v0 >> 5)) + v0) ^ (sum + k[(sum>>11) & 3]);
        sum -= delta;
        v0 -= (((v1 << 4) ^ (v1 >> 5)) + v1) ^ (sum + k[sum & 3]);
    }
    w[0]=v0; w[1]=v1;
}

void TeaDecode ( const std::string& str, const std::string& key, std::string* out )
{
    unsigned int v[2];
    unsigned int w[2];
    unsigned int k[4];
    unsigned int keybuffer [ 4 ];

    // Clear buffers
    memset ( v, 0, sizeof(v) );
    memset ( w, 0, sizeof(w) );
    memset ( k, 0, sizeof(k) );
    memset ( keybuffer, 0, sizeof(keybuffer) );
    out->clear ();

    // Count the number of passes that we need
    int numBlocks = str.length() / 4;
    int numPasses = numBlocks - 1;

    if ( numPasses <= 0 )
        return;

    // Process the key
    int len = key.length ();
    if ( len > 16 )
        len = 16;
    memcpy ( keybuffer, key.c_str(), len );
    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
        k[i] = keybuffer[i];

    // Create a temporary buffer to store the result
    unsigned char* buffer = new unsigned char [ numPasses * 4 + 4 ];
    memset ( buffer, 0, numPasses * 4 + 4 );

    // Decode it!
    const char* p = str.c_str();
    v[1] = *(unsigned int*)&p[numPasses * 4];
    for ( int i = 0; i < numPasses; ++i )
    {
        v[0] = *(unsigned int*)&p[(numPasses-i-1)*4];
        decodeXtea ( &v[0], &w[0], &k[0] );
        *(unsigned int*)&buffer[(numPasses-i-1)*4] = w[0];
        v[1] = w[1];
    }

    out->assign ( (char *)buffer, numPasses*4 );
    delete [] buffer;
}

void encodeXtea(unsigned int* v, unsigned int* w, unsigned int* k) {
    register unsigned int v0=v[0], v1=v[1], i, sum=0;
    register unsigned int delta=0x9E3779B9;
    for(i=0; i<32; i++) {
       v0 += (((v1 << 4) ^ (v1 >> 5)) + v1) ^ (sum + k[sum & 3]);
        sum += delta;
        v1 += (((v0 << 4) ^ (v0 >> 5)) + v0) ^ (sum + k[(sum>>11) & 3]);
    }
    w[0]=v0; w[1]=v1;
}

void TeaEncode ( const std::string& str, const std::string& key, std::string* out )
{
    unsigned int v[2];
    unsigned int w[2];
    unsigned int k[4];
    unsigned int keybuffer [ 4 ];

    // Clear buffers
    memset ( v, 0, sizeof(v) );
    memset ( w, 0, sizeof(w) );
    memset ( k, 0, sizeof(k) );
    memset ( keybuffer, 0, sizeof(keybuffer) );
    out->clear ();

    // Process the key
    int len = key.length ();
    if ( len > 16 )
        len = 16;
    memcpy ( keybuffer, key.c_str(), len );
    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
        k[i] = keybuffer[i];

    // Copy the input string to a buffer of size multiple of 4
    int strbuflen = str.length ();
    if ( strbuflen == 0 )
        return;
    if ( (strbuflen % 4) > 0 )
        strbuflen += 4 - (strbuflen % 4);
    unsigned char* strbuf = new unsigned char [ strbuflen ];
    memset ( strbuf, 0, strbuflen );
    memcpy ( strbuf, str.c_str(), str.length() );

    // Encode it!
    v[1] = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < strbuflen; i += 4 )
    {
        v[0] = *(unsigned int*)&strbuf[i];

        encodeXtea ( &v[0], &w[0], &k[0] );
        out->append ( (char*)&w[0], 4 );

        v[1] = w[1];
    }
    out->append ( (char*)&v[1], 4 );

    delete [] strbuf;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This fixed it.

```
void readSystem(string fname,string outFileName,string key,string mode)
{
    //size_t buffer_size = 1<<20;
    size_t buffer_size;
    if(mode == "E")
    {
        buffer_size = 32;
    }
    else
    {
        buffer_size = 36;   
    }
    //char *buffer = new char[buffer_size];
    string buffer(buffer_size,'\0');
    string data,output;

    //data.resize(buffer_size);

    // The input
    std::ifstream fin(fname,ios::binary);
    // The output
    ofstream outFile(outFileName,ios::binary);// | ios::app);

    // Anti overwrite
    if(getSize(outFileName) > 0)
    {
        cout << "Overwrite error" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    while (fin)
    {
        // Try to read next chunk of data
    //  fin.read(buffer, buffer_size);
        fin.read(&buffer.front(), buffer_size);
        // Get the number of bytes actually read
        size_t count = fin.gcount();
        data = buffer;

        //data = encode(data,key);

        if(mode == "E")
        {
            data = encode(data,key);
        }
        if(mode == "D")
        {
            data = decode(data,key);
        }

        //blockXor(data,key);
        //outFile.write(data.c_str(),count);
        outFile.write(data.c_str(),data.length());      
        // If nothing has been read, break

        if (!count) 
            break;      
        // Do whatever you need with first count bytes in the buffer
    }
    outFile.close();
    fin.close();
//  delete[] buffer;

}
```

Comment: If you're going to answer your own question you might point out what the difference is between the two sets of code and why.  Someone shouldn't need to diff them to figure it out.